# UTF-8 characters displayed as question mark in the Powershell of new Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal

Japanese characters and Chinese characters, as well as emoji characters, are shown as ?(question marks) in the Powershell window of the new Windows Terminal(installed from the Microsoft Store), and the Japanese and Chinese characters can be correctly shown in CMD window while the emoji characters still can not.

Microsoft claims that the new Windows Terminal supports the utf8 characters well but why can this happen? Are there any options to turn on the utf8 support?

OS version: 10.0.19042

Comment: It's not enough that the _application_ supports Unicode, the _font_ must have support too. If the font doesn't have, say, kanji glyphs, displaying U+4e20 丠 is kind of hard.

Comment: @vonPryz Thanks for your comment! I've already set the `faceFont` property for that but that doesn't work.

Comment: Version 1.8.1092.0 displays japanese ok for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @vonPryz said, the Windows Terminal itself supports Unicode characters.
If you want to handle Japanese characters in PowerShell, you have to change the codepage of your console to `932`.

Note that when you change the codepage of the console, first you have to run `cmd.exe` from PowerShell, then change the codepage in your console with `chcp`, and run `powershell.exe`. If you run `chcp` directly from PowerShell, it shows Japanese characters as `?`.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.985]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>chcp 932 & powershell

(Whole screen is cleared)

現在のコード ページ: 932
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

新しいクロスプラットフォームの PowerShell をお試しください https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\> Write-Host "日本語"
日本語
```

[image]

You can handle Japanese AND Chinese characters with `chcp 65001`.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.985]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>chcp 65001 & powershell
Active code page: 65001
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\> Write-Host "日本語"
日本語
PS C:\> Write-Host "汉语"
汉语
```

[image]

Also, note that `powershell.exe` cannot handle emoji characters and causes `System.Text.EncoderFallbackException` in codepage 65001 because it uses surrogate-pair (`powershell.exe` cannot handle surrogate pair correctly in codepage 65001).

- Windows Terminal version: 1.7.1033.0
- OS Version: Windows 10 Version 2004 (Build 19401.985)

Comment: Recently I met the same issue. The above solution can solve my problem, but it is a little cumbersome. A better way is shown [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62210/apostrophes-showing-up-as-%ce%93%c3%87%c3%96-after-converting-from-windows-to-linux/393600#393600) with `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Console]::InputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` added in to the pwsh's `$PROFILE`